# How to bind to a collection without using an index of the collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, collections

I am trying to learn the MVVM pattern in WPF and I am running into some issues with bindings and collections. I don't like binding to the index of the collection because the collection changes.

I have `MyModelClass : ObservableCollection<MyData>`

The `MyData` class has a property called `DataValue` in it to hold my custom information. I fill the `MyModelClass` with `MyData` objects. In the view model class (`MyViewModel`) I have a property `CurrentData` of type `MyModelClass`.

Now in this case, my binding is to a combo box. 
Here is what the binding looks like:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbxData" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentData}"
  DisplayMemberPath="DataValue"
  SelectedValuePath="DataValue"
  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentData[0].DataValue}"/>
```

This all works fine and the `MyViewModel` class has the interface setup for PropertyChanged notifications.
I need to refresh the information this holds every few seconds.

I am refreshing the collection by doing something like this inside the `MyModelClass`:

```
public Class MyModelClass : ObservableCollection<MyData>
{
    private static MyModelClass current = null;
    public static MyModelClass Current
    {
        get
        {
             if(current == null)
                 current = new MyModelClass();

             return current;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateModel(MyData newData)
    {
         MyModelClass newModel = new MyModelClass();
         newModel.Add(newData);
         current = newModel;

    }
}
```

Inside `MyViewModel` there is this:

```
MyModelClass CurrentData = MyModelClass.Current;
```

I tried my best to give as much code as I could and keep it simple. Please let me know if there is more needed to clarify. Thank you for any suggestions on how to fix my issue.

In case you missed it:
Problem: How can I bind to the collection, or the value I want to display in the collection, without using the index like I have shown above (`SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentData[0].DataValue}"`)? How can I fix this or change my implementation to be correct?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you implementing a collection type when you only want one item in the collection? If you want the current item you need another property which points to the current item

Comment: I agree this is confusing to me also, but that is another problem I had where I was unable to get the binding to update when the properties changed unless it was in a collection. However, that is a separate problem from this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property on MyModelClass called "SelectedData" or something similiar.
Then bind that property to the SelectedItem property of ComboBox

Comment: Make sure you make it a dependencyproperty otherwise it won't notify the UI of changes to itself - that was probably where you were going wrong before - just to clarify, a dependency property will notify when the property changes, not when the underlying object changes - this is good for 'SelectedItem'. If you also want the underlying object to notify it needs to implement a .NET notification interface (INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am marking this accepted because you did answer my original question. The notification to the UI is a separate topic. Thanks again for the suggestions and help.

Comment: In a ViewModel you want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. You dont want to add it as a dependency property.

Comment: Yeah for some reason my brain just ignored all the references to MVVM :) I was thinking UserControls/FrameworkElements - probably because I'm writing some :P